# Can't install anything anymore, unmet dependencies for linux-image-

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Whenever I try to install anything I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang : Depends: clang-3.4 (>= 3.4~rc3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However, when I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-corba erlang-crypto erlang-diameter
  erlang-edoc erlang-eldap erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic
  erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon
  erlang-parsetools erlang-percept erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools
  erlang-snmp erlang-ssh erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools
  erlang-webtool erlang-xmerl libsctp1 linux-headers-3.16.0-30
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-41
  linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-43
  linux-headers-3.16.0-43-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-45
  linux-headers-3.16.0-45-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-48
  linux-headers-3.16.0-48-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-51
  linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic linux-headers-3.16.0-52
  linux-headers-3.16.0-52-generic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic lksctp-tools
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 295 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 478639 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic (3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/abi-3.16.0-57-generic' to '/boot/abi-3.16.0-57-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic_3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic (3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic_3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic_3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My boot partition is almost full (98,7%), and it has quite a few images, but I can't remove them because I get the same message then.

```
~$ ls /boot
abi-3.16.0-30-generic         initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
abi-3.16.0-41-generic         lost+found
abi-3.16.0-43-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.16.0-45-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.16.0-46-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.16.0-48-generic         System.map-3.16.0-30-generic
abi-3.16.0-49-generic         System.map-3.16.0-41-generic
abi-3.16.0-51-generic         System.map-3.16.0-43-generic
config-3.16.0-30-generic      System.map-3.16.0-45-generic
config-3.16.0-41-generic      System.map-3.16.0-46-generic
config-3.16.0-43-generic      System.map-3.16.0-48-generic
config-3.16.0-45-generic      System.map-3.16.0-49-generic
config-3.16.0-46-generic      System.map-3.16.0-51-generic
config-3.16.0-48-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
config-3.16.0-49-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-41-generic
config-3.16.0-51-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-43-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.16.0-45-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-41-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-43-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
initrd.img-3.16.0-45-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
```

Comment: Try removing old kernels to free up some room https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: I get the same dependency errors when using either apt-get or dpkg for removing those old kernels

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: I tried the solution in that post but dpkg and apt-get wont work

Comment: Seriously, always use Ubuntu's default partition scheme. Simply don't have any separate partitions, put everything in a single one and be happy. Remove your old kernels and consider increasing /boot's size OR merging it with /.

Comment: I havent set any special partition scheme as far as I k ow. Is it safe to just remove those files?

Answer (score 0):

When using a separate boot partition, after a number of upgrades you will have to remove the old kernel images.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove clang
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic linux-image-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic linux-3.16.0-48-generic
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install clang
```

Alternatively, you can delete some of the older files on the boot partition, though you will get a few errors before it is straightened out.

For Example:

```
sudo rm -f /boot/*-3.16.0-30-*  /boot/*-3.16.0-41-* /boot/*-3.16.0-43-* /boot/*-3.16.0-45-* /boot/*-3.16.0-46-* /boot/*-3.16.0-48-*
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic linux-image-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic linux-3.16.0-48-generic
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install clang
```

Good luck.