# Can't purge old kernels (dependency problems), but /boot is out of space

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, dependencies

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and I'm trying to install a new package using apt-get. Unfortunately, whenever I try I get messages like:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-3.16.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic (= 3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Doing some googling, I found that [this can be caused by lack of space on the boot partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719481/cant-install-anything-anymore-unmet-dependencies-for-linux-image) (and sure enough, `df` shows `/boot` at 100%). However, any time I try running the `apt-get` commands in the accepted answer there, I get the same errors as above.

Looking for another solution that didn't use `apt-get`, I came across [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels), which recommends using things like `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.2.0-15-generic` on old, unused kernels.

`dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)` (from the afore-mentioned post) shows that I have several old kernels in the `pi` state (desired purged, state is installed according to [this](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/))

`uname -r` tells me the kernel I'm running is 3.16.0-62-generic, so I thought I should be safe to remove these old kernels. However, trying to do so with things like `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic` results in:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic
```

Garrg! I'm at my wit's end, and out of my depth (don't really know much about dpkg or apt-get), so I need some help.

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I uninstall the old kernels with `dpkg`?
2. If that question can't be directly solved, I guess ultimately I want to know: *What do I need to do to get into a state where I can install new packages again?*

---

**Other things I have tried**:

- `sudo apt-get autoremove` : results in the original error about unmet dependencies
- `sudo apt-get -f autoremove` : results in:

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic (3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

**Note**: I've migrated this question from ["Unix & Linux Stack Exchange"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281752/cant-purge-old-kernels-dependency-problems-but-boot-is-out-of-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `uname -r` to show your currently running kernel. DO NOT DELETE anything with this version number.

You can find which packages the kernels in `/boot` belong to:

```
for i in /boot/vmlinuz* ; do 
    dpkg -S $i| egrep -v $(uname -r)
done
```

You can remove these packages with `sudo apt-get purge` *packagename ...*.

You can find more packages related to the kernels to be deleted by looking for other packages with the same version number:

To extract the version numbers:

```
for i in /boot/vmlinuz* ; do 
    dpkg -S $i | egrep -v $(uname -r)
done |cut -d- -f3-4
```

To find other packages with the same version numbers:

```
for j in $(
    for i in /boot/vmlinuz* ; do 
        dpkg -S $i| egrep -v $(uname -r)
    done |cut -d- -f3-4 ) ; 
do 
     dpkg -l "*$j*" | egrep '^ii|^rc'
done
```

To automate deleting all kernels other than the current kernel, and all packages whose versions match the deleted kernels (**Danger, Wil Robinson**):

Simply append

```
| awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run purge
```

to the previous code fragment. WHen you're sure it does what you want, remove `--dry-run`.

If your `/boot` is so full that you cannot delete packages, you can make some space on `/boot` by removing the oldest `/boot/initrd.img*` file,

Comment: The key was "If your /boot is so full that you cannot delete packages, you can make some space on /boot by removing the oldest /boot/initrd.img* file". After that I did a `sudo apt-get -f install`, then running `sudo apt-get remove -f linux-image-3.16.0-<various old versions>-generic` worked for me.

Comment: Doing the `sudo apt-get -f install` after you have freed a tiny percentage of the space on `/boot` risks filling `/boot` mid-install. It would have been safer to do the whole cleanup first. When I used it, I manually preserved more versions by inserting `| egrep -v '3.19.0-56|3.19.0-58'` just after the `awk` command. YMMV.

Comment: I should mention that I cleaned out *all* of the initrd.img files except the one for the current kernel, which left me with 40% in boot. I'll try to keep boot from filling up again, but if it does, next time I'll clean out more before the `apt-get -f install`.

Comment: By deleting all but the latest `initrd.img` files, you broke all the other kernels. Reasonableness calls for keeping a spare version or two.